# [API Platform][Symfony 4] How to add an endpoint in Swagger (OpenAPI)?

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, api-platform.com

I use Symfony Flex and Composer with the Symfony 4 and installed API Platform's server component in my app.

How to add an endpoint in Swagger (OpenAPI) for custom controller?

```
<?php
/**
 * Application features
 */

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Checks if the service is alive.
 *
 * @package Behat\Behat\Context\Context
 */
class HealthcheckController
{
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     name="api_healthcheck_entrypoint",
     *     path="/api/ping",
     *     methods={"GET"},
     * )
     */
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return new JsonResponse(array('ping' => 'pong'));
    }
}
```

docker-compose exec php bin/console api:swagger:export

```
    {
        "swagger": "2.0",
        "basePath": "\/",
        "info": {
            "title": "FastTony.es",
            "version": "0.0.1"
        },
        "paths": {},
        "securityDefinitions": {
            "apiKey": {
                "type": "apiKey",
                "in": "header",
                "description": "Value for the Authorization header",
                "name": "Authorization"
            }
        },
        "security": [
            {
                "apiKey": []
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do that in the entity. You must have ApiResource annotation so you can add custom operations there. In this case, you have to put this annotation:

```
 *          "api_healthcheck_entrypoint"={
 *              "controller"=HealthcheckControllerAction::class,
 *              "method"="GET",
 *              "path"="/api/ping
 *              "defaults"={"_api_receive"=false},",
 *              "normalization_context"={
 *                  "groups"={"ping"}
 *              }
```

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers

Comment: So... Why are you using API Platform if you are not following his philosophy? If you check the documentation, you have 3 ways for do this:

* Annotations in the entity
* XML
* yaml

but not in the controller...

Comment: You don't necessarily need an Entity but you do need a class to set as resource. See the [General Design Considerations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/design/). Also see [Aperation without entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744246/operation-without-entity) and [How to write custom endpoints with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589694/how-to-write-custom-endpoints-with-parameters-not-related-to-any-specific-entity).